# How many distributions of $18$ different objects into $3$ different boxes.

Tags: combinatorics

How many distributions of $18$ different objects into $3$ different boxes are there with twice as many objects in one box as in the other two combined$?$

Soln:

It appears to me as an arrangement problem with repetition of some sort.  As such I did this:  $$\binom{3}{1} \frac{18!}{(2n)! n! n! }$$

i did $\binom{3}{1}$ to account for the fact any of the $3$ boxes could get the double amount.  $\frac{18!}{(2n)! n! n! }$ was done partially because I have seen a formula relating to this sort of problem,  but personally I am trying to understand the REASON behind why this formula works here, that is if my treatment was correct

Comment: how is that " twice" as many as the other two combined?

Comment: The question doesn't say the two other boxes must be equal. Better to do: $${3 \choose 1}\frac{18!}{(2(n+m))!n!m!}$$ where $3n+3m=18$ so it becomes: $${3 \choose 1}\frac{18!}{12!n!(6-n)!}$$

Comment: What is $n$? You can't use a variable that you haven't even defined!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to think about this problem:

1) You have 18 objects, you need to choose 12 (see my comment) to put in the first bag. You can do this in ${18 \choose 12}$ ways. You then need to take the remaining 6 objects and put $n$ of them in the second bag. This can be done in ${6 \choose n}$ ways. The total is therefore:

$${18 \choose 12}\times{6 \choose n}=\frac{18!}{12!6!}\times\frac{6!}{n!(6-n)!}=\frac{18!}{12!n!(6-n)!}$$

2) You imagine the balls are numbered from 1 to 18 and each bag has a letter on it: A, B, C. You now want 12 balls corresponding to A, $n$ balls corresponding to B and $6-n$ balls corresponding to C. This is the same as rearranging the 12 copies of an object A, $n$ copies of an object B and $6-n$ copies of an object C. There are $18!$ ways to arrange these objects. However due to the repeats we need to divide by $12!$ to account for interchanging all the object A's. Similarly divide by $n!$ to account for interchanging all the object B's and divide by $6-n$ to account for interchanging all the object C's.

$$$$

Final Note: You only need the value ${3 \choose 1}$ if the bags are somehow distinct or have an order to them. If they are identical leave out that term.

Comment: it amazrs me how what may take me 15-20 mins to just get moving in tge right direction you guys have a well written informative solution. .....thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. I gave a very similar problem to my class this week so I had the explanation fresh in my mind from when they asked.

Answer (score 2):

If you have $18$ items, the big box must have $12$ and the other two must have $6$ between them. There are $18 \choose 12$ ways to select the ones in the big box, $3$ ways to select the big box, now distribute the other $6$.

Answer (score -1):

Out of $18$ we select any of the $12$ objects to be placed into any of the $3$ boxes.This can be done in $3*\binom{18}{12}$ ways.There remain $6$ distinct objects to be distributed into $2$ distinct boxes.This can be done in $64$ ways.    $P(6;0,6)+P(6;1,5)+P(6;2,4)+P(6;3,3)+P(6;4,2)+P(6;5,1)+P(6;6,0)=64...$